# Determining friction for unbalanced wheel to roll without sliding

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

I'm trying to model a weighted wheel rolling without slipping. I understand that friction, by virtue of being an off-center force, affects both linear and angular acceleration. So my train-of-thought was to:

- Describe linear acceleration in terms of it's forces parallel to the ground; $a = (F_{wheel} + F_{imbalance} + F_{friction}) / m$, where $m = m_{wheel} + m_{imbalance}$
- Describe angular acceleration in terms of it's tangential forces; $α = r * (F_{imbalance'} + F_{friction}) / I$, where $I = I_{wheel} + I_{imbalance}$
- Relate linear and angular acceleration; $a = -r * α$
- Solve for the frictional force; $F_{friction} = -(m * r^2 * F_{imbalance'} + I * (F_{wheel} + F_{imbalance})) / (m * r^2 + I)$
- Solve for a with the new $F_{friction}$ force and translate the wheel based on time; $v += a * t, p += v * t$
- Rotate the wheel based on distance translated; $θ = -p / r$

When I programmed this up it didn't look that convincing, and I don't know where I went wrong. The effect was very subtle even when I increased the mass of the imbalance. This left me wondering if I made a bad choice for $F_{imbalance}$ or $F_{imbalance'}$, or if my handling of the directions/signs while converting between vectors/scalar magnitudes was wrong.

- I used the vector that lies along B in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXDzY.jpg) picture for $F_{imbalance}$
- I used the vector that is perpendicular to A in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxeJZ.jpg) picture for $F_{imbalance'}$

As for vectors/scalars, I tried to do most of the calculations with vectors. This meant rotating the $F_{imbalance'}$ to be parallel with the ground. Does anyone see any glaring errors with my approach?

Comment: Note that linear acceleration has two components. You are forgetting the $\omega^2 r$ part.

Comment: Is the initial position of the imbalance in any particular orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surprisingly complex problem. To avoid trying to find the combined center of gravity and mass moment of inertia you can split it up into two rigid bodies each with $m_1$, $I_1$ and $m_2$ and $I_2$ for mass and mass moment of inertia that are glued together transmitting forces $\vec{F}_B$ and torques $\tau_B$.

First the kinematics. Let us decide the unknown variable to be the orientation of the wheel $\varphi$ relative to when the imbalance is touching the ground. If the ramp slope is $\theta$ then location of the center of the wheel *C* is
$$\vec{r}_C = \begin{pmatrix} r \sin\theta-\varphi r \cos\theta \\r \cos \theta + \varphi r \sin\theta \\0  \end{pmatrix} $$ with positive $\varphi$ going up the ramp and negative down. Also positive *x*-axis points points towars the lower part of the ramp.

The contact point *A* is located at

$$\vec{r}_A = \begin{pmatrix} -\varphi r \cos\theta \\\varphi r \sin\theta \\0  \end{pmatrix} $$

The imbalance center *B* is located at
$$\vec{r}_B = \begin{pmatrix} r \sin\theta-\varphi r \cos\theta + r \sin(\varphi-\theta) \\r \cos \theta + \varphi r \sin\theta - r \cos(\varphi-\theta) \\0  \end{pmatrix} $$

No we need the accleration at *C* and *B* which is found by
$$ \vec{v}_C = \frac{{\rm d} \vec{r_C}}{{\rm d} t} = \frac{\partial \vec{r}_C}{\partial \varphi} \dot{\varphi} $$
$$ \vec{a}_C = \frac{{\rm d} \vec{v_C}}{{\rm d} t} = \frac{\partial \vec{v}_C}{\partial \varphi} \omega +  \frac{\partial \vec{v}_C}{\partial \omega} \alpha$$
where $\omega = \dot \varphi$ and $\alpha = \ddot \varphi $.
$$ \vec{v}_B = \frac{{\rm d} \vec{r_B}}{{\rm d} t} = \frac{\partial \vec{r}_B}{\partial \varphi} \dot{\varphi} $$
$$ \vec{a}_B = \frac{{\rm d} \vec{v_B}}{{\rm d} t} = \frac{\partial \vec{v}_B}{\partial \varphi} \omega +  \frac{\partial \vec{v}_B}{\partial \omega} \alpha$$

With the end result of
$$ \vec{a}_C = \begin{pmatrix} -\alpha r \cos(\theta) \\ \alpha r \sin(\theta) \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
$$ \vec{a}_B = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha r \cos(\varphi-\theta)-\omega^2 r \sin(\varphi-\theta)-\alpha r \cos\theta\\ \alpha r \sin(\varphi-\theta)+\omega^2 r \cos(\varphi-\theta)+\alpha r \sin\theta\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Now for the equations of motion.

If $\vec{n}=(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta,0)$ is the normal to the slope and $\vec{e}=(\cos\theta,-\sin\theta,0)$ is tangent to the slope downwards, the the sum of the forces on the two bodies are:

$$ N \,\vec{n} - F\, \vec{e} - \vec{F}_B + m_1 \vec{g} = m_1 \vec{a}_C $$
$$ \vec{F}_B + m_2 \vec{g} = m_2 \vec{a}_B $$
where $F$ is the friction force required and $N$ the contact force. The sum of the torques on the two bodies are:

$$ \vec{\tau}_B = I_2 \vec{\alpha} $$
$$ (\vec{r}_A-\vec{r}_C) \times (N\, \vec{n}-F\, \vec{e}) - (\vec{r}_B-\vec{r}_C)\times \vec{F}_B - \vec{\tau}_B = I_1 \vec{\alpha} $$

where $\vec{\alpha} = (0,0,\alpha)$.

The above equations have 6 non-zero components, are used to solve for the following variables. Two in $\vec{F}_B$, and one in $\vec{\tau}_B$, $\alpha$, $N$, $F$, for a six total.

The calculate the required coefficient of friction for non-slip as $\mu =| \frac{F}{N} |$.

Note this assumes the problem is planar, and ignores the whole 3x3 inertia matrix with the gyroscopic torques. It helps to project the sum of forces along $\vec{e}$ and $\vec{n}$ to extract out $F$ and $N$ cleanly.

Comment: How do you solve for $\mu$? It doesn't appear in any of the equations. Is $F$ assumed to have some form that depends on $\mu$? I'm confused.

Comment: You calculate $F$ and $N$ at all times, and you need $\mu \ge \frac{F}{N}$ to maintain traction. Note that the normal force $N$ changes as the wheel goes around.

Comment: I think I see. You mean compute $F(t)$ and $N(t)$ in terms of $\phi(t)$ and $\omega(t)$. But then how do you compute $\phi(t)$ and $\omega(t)$? I'm trying to solve for dynamics of an unbalanced wheel rolling (or rocking) on a level surface and this seemed like a similar question but it doesn't seem possible to solve the above equations for position and momentum.

Comment: @DanielGenin - To solve the dynamics, you need a simulation. Then at each time frame, once the forces are computed, the required traction $\mu$ is calculated and compared to the available friction coefficient to decide how to proceed to the next step (slip or no slip). Note that for each time step positions and velocities are given.

Comment: Thank you, John. I'm still holding out hope for a closed form solution or at least a set of ODE's that can be solved numerically. Going to keep looking.

Comment: @DanielGenin - given the motor torque, the force of propulsion changes as the wheel goes around because the radius of contact changes. You can integrate to find speed vs position, but integrating to get time would require a closed elliptical integral of the first kind I think. I haven't worked out the math here, but I have done a lot of work with cam mechanisms and this is similar.

Comment: I don't know how to respond more directly to Mr. Alexiou but I wanted to convey how important walking me through this solution was to me generally understanding applied math. Absolutely brilliant.